# Cannot access WCF Service running inside Parallels from outside

Tags: macos, wcf, virtual-machine, parallels

I have a WCF service which is working perfect inside of my Parallels Bootcamp VM

However, I cannot get this working from outside, i.e. the MAC that parallels is running on

The IP address is shown as 10.211.55.3 using IP Config

The service is running via port 17377 so I am trying to use the URL 'http :// 10.211.55.3: 17377/CalculatorService.svc'

It appears as though this is normally caused by firewall issues

However, the firewall is off on both the windows VM and my MAC

Has anyone got any other ideas about what the problem could be?

I have tried this with another WCF service and still have the same problem, the 10.... IP address errors with invalid hostname

Paul

Answer (score 0):

This has now been fixed thanks

If anyone else ever gets a similar issue to this the easiest thing is to change the parallels network to host only although this does disconnect the internet

I had to do that as well as modifyibg the host file on both the vm and mac to link the machines IP address to an specific host I gave it